# Arcane magic and divine magic detect/identify

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic

As there is no mentioning of it in the rules I'm wondering:

Does it make a difference if detect magic is cast from an arcane or divine caster?
Thus does detect magic always detect BOTH types of magic or only the same type as the spell is (thus only arcane or divine)

The same question also for identify magic.

Or summarized: Is there any difference between divine / arcane magic in terms of detecting / identifying it (aside from the appropriate knowledge skill)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No, there's no difference.**  *Detect magic* would say if there was.  Both types can detect the other's magic equally well.

Technically, not the even the different Knowledge skills apply to detecting magic itself.  They apply to identifying the *results* of the two different kinds of magic, though, based on which one creates them most commonly - undead fall into Religion while constructs fall into Arcana.  Note that this part isn't straightforward either;  both kinds can *summon* outsiders (Know: Planes) and animals/magical beasts (Nature; which is associated with divine casters specifically through the Druid and Ranger).

For identifying actual *spells*, either as they are cast or by studying their ongoing effects with *detect magic* (and identifying magic items with either *detect magic* or *identify*), you use the Spellcraft skill.  This doesn't change regardless of your or the other caster's traditions.  Note that many spells that at first glance clearly belong on one side or the other quickly get mixed up when classes besides wizard and cleric get added to the mix.

> Bards' spell lists read more like a cleric's with access to a few good wizard buffs.  *Cure* spells, party buffs, and sonic damage like *soundburst*....
>
> Domains, familiars, mysteries, and to a lesser extent bloodlines love to grant spells from the "other side".  A Fire/Magic cleric has access to common wizard spells, for just a quick example.

Comment: for the knowledge: yepp although do the identify magic spells also not differ between both types?

Comment: @ThomasE. Updated to including identifying spells, ongoing magical effects, and magic items.

Comment: ok so an arcane identify can help identifying a divine item

Comment: @ThomasE. the only items that are naturally arcane or divine are spell completion items (scrolls), because they're actually just copies of the spell on them ready to be cast.  Even wands aren't either divine or arcane - a bard (arcane) can use a cleric's (divine) wand of *cure light wounds* just fine.  The only requirement is that the bard be able to cast the spell in the wand, not cast the divine or the arcane form of the spell.  They have different *sources*, but they're functionally identical.  The lists are just different in theme, which is why divine casters don't normally have fireball.

Comment: that is what i wasn't 100% sure about (if aside from sources they are absolutely identical). tnx

Comment: **Pedantry!:** I have no idea why, but *Pathfinder* eliminated from the skill [Spellcraft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/spellcraft) the *D&D 3.5* ability of the skill [Spellcraft](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/spellcraft.htm) to identify a spell in place; that's now a [Knowledge (arcana)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/knowledge) skill check.

Comment: I'd have to double-check that Pathfinder has the same rule, but in 3.5, there **is** an important difference between the arcane and divine versions of *identify*: the components line lists "DF/M" and the spell description ends with the "Arcane Material Component" description -- when cast as a divine spell, *identify* does not cost 100 gp.

Comment: @Kryan yeah, the differences in actually *casting* the magic are huge.  For example, a cleric can cast identify without cost, wearing full plate and carrying a tower shield.  But identifying/countering/detecting the spell still works the same, assuming you can even see the cleric (as we all know, tower shields make you invisible).